# MVC - One model with multiple views in Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller, model, view

I am looking at a basic example of MVC patterns in Java and I am unsure how to add more than one view to a model. This is my code currently:

```
public class Student {
   private String rollNo;
   private String name;

   public String getRollNo() {
      return rollNo;
   }

   public void setRollNo(String rollNo) {
      this.rollNo = rollNo;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}

public class StudentView {
   public void printStudentDetails(String studentName, String studentRollNo){
      System.out.println("Student: ");
      System.out.println("Name: " + studentName);
      System.out.println("Roll No: " + studentRollNo);
   }
}

public class StudentController {
   private Student model;
   private StudentView view;

   public StudentController(Student model, StudentView view){
      this.model = model;
      this.view = view;
   }

   public void setStudentName(String name){
      model.setName(name);      
   }

   public String getStudentName(){
      return model.getName();       
   }

   public void setStudentRollNo(String rollNo){
      model.setRollNo(rollNo);      
   }

   public String getStudentRollNo(){
      return model.getRollNo();     
   }

   public void updateView(){                
      view.printStudentDetails(model.getName(), model.getRollNo());
   }    
}

public class MVCPatternDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      //fetch student record based on his roll no from the database
      Student model  = retriveStudentFromDatabase();

      //Create a view : to write student details on console
      StudentView view = new StudentView();

      StudentController controller = new StudentController(model, view);

      controller.updateView();

      //update model data
      controller.setStudentName("John");

      controller.updateView();
   }

   private static Student retriveStudentFromDatabase(){
      Student student = new Student();
      student.setName("Robert");
      student.setRollNo("10");
      return student;
   }
}
```

The issue I have found with the controller is that it only accepts a view of class type 'StudentView'. How would I alter this example so that it would take a number of different classes as views, for example 'SwingView'.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
public interface Views {
   public void printStudentDetails(String studentName, String      studentRollNo);
}

public class StudentView implements Views
{

    public void printStudentDetails(String studentName, String studentRollNo)
    {
       String display =  "Name: " + studentName + "Roll No: " +    studentRollNo;
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,display);
    }
}
```

I you want something more flashy you could make StudentView extends JPanel and the MVCPatternDemo a JFrame